# list slide titles in a combo box

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new in VBA programming.
How can I create a list (`combo box`) from my slides? the option `value` is `slide index` and title is slide title (or name)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, maybe:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim sTemp As String

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSl.Shapes.HasTitle Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
        Else
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem CStr(oSl.SlideIndex)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that this should pick up text from the title placeholders but won't get text that just happens to *look* like a title.